# Getting nearby locations

Tags: iphone

I want to get nearby cities from current location depending upon distance, e.g, cities in radius of 100km,200km etc using the gps of iphone. How can i determine these cties as gps only gives the details of the current location.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a database of the cities in your program, with their coordinates.

You'll read the coordinates of the iphone from the GPS, and then find the x closest cities to you by simple math ([see this answer for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906280/how-to-get-10-nearest-locations-from-the-current-location))

Answer (score 0):

You will have to have a custom list of cities and their respective locations and work it out yourself, or potentially use something like google local api, but I don't know if you could reliably return cities through it.